# how remove item Due to the character previous item of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a problem with remove from list
i have a list look like below:

```
my_list = ['asf', 'fds.', 'all']
```

i want print my_list with one Condition;
if '.' is in Previous item don't print item(and don't deleted) look like output below:

```
['asf', 'fds.']
```

please help me tnx.

Comment: Pretty standard `for` loop task that you've basically described. What was the issue with your implementation?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please see [ask] and [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Do you want to remove everything after `'fds.'` or do you just not want to print it? Your title and question has conflicting information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension

```
[val for idx,val in enumerate(my_list) if (idx==0) or (idx>=1  and '.' not in my_list[idx-1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using enumerate:

```
my_list = ['asf', 'fds.', 'all']

new_list = [ item for i, item in enumerate(my_list) if i == 0 or '.' not in my_list[i-1] ]
```

or a solution using zip:

```
[my_list[0]] + [ current for prev,current in zip(my_list,my_list[1:]) if '.' not in prev]
```